# Using applicationDidBecomeActive To Check If User Logged In

Tags: ios, objective-c, security

I have an app that has a "Home Screen" with login and register options. When a user completes one of the above the data is stored in a shared instance. Now for security reasons I was looking at using the `applicationDidBecomeActive` to periodically check to make sure the user is still active on the server or not blocked by calling a method in the shared instance. If the user is not active the app kicks them to the home screen with a prompt.

My issue is however that when the app loads for the first time `applicationDidBecomeActive is called and because the user is not logged in you end up with a loop.

What is the correct approach for dealing with this issue? Ideally I want to use applicationDidBecomeActive but I only want to perform the check whilst in the account section of the app.

Any help would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: pls show the code of how you are checking in the applicationDidBecomeActive method.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways of implementing this.

Way 1: Fire a Notification using `NotificationCenter.default` and implement a listener in your Accounts-ViewController.

Way 2: In your AppDelegate, get active ViewController (depends on which rootViewController you are using) and if that ViewController has the type `AccountVC` trigger a public function.

Way 3: Combine or use Way1 and Way2 in a different object and notify your ViewController in your preferred way.

And many more.
Post some code for more specific help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use either of the following methods to deal with the issue.

**Approach 1**

```
- (void)checkWhetherAppIsActive {

     UIApplicationState appState = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationState];
     if (appState == UIApplicationStateActive) {

     }else if (appState == UIApplicationStateInactive) {

     }else if (appState == UIApplicationStateBackground) {

     }
}
```

**Approach 2**

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification object:nil queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] usingBlock:^(NSNotification * _Nonnull note) {

}];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification object:nil queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] usingBlock:^(NSNotification * _Nonnull note) {

}];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification object:nil queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] usingBlock:^(NSNotification * _Nonnull note) {

}];
```

Answer (score 0):

When the user logs in , generate an `expiryTimeStamp`. And whenever the app is active, you can check the `currentTimestamp` to `expiryTimeStamp` . If the `currentTimestamp` is before the `expiryTimeStamp`, then consider it as active session!

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    //compare current NSDate with expiryDate
    if(current date is before expiry date){
         //active session
      }else{
     //log out the user
    }
}
```

You can generate expiry date as:

```
-(void)generateExpiryTimeStamp{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:900] forKey:@"tokenExpiry"];  //Expiry date Set to 15mins
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];
}
```